# ePSXe on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 doesn't seem to recognize correctly D-pad

Tags: 16.04, emulation, joystick

I'm here with a problem on my boyfriend's pc:
I recently installed ePSXe 2.0.5, but we can't play any games because of an error recognizing the joypad; more specifically *it doesn't seem to accept the **up button** of D-pad...*

**Important**: *I installed `jstest` and it seems all correct; every button and axis does its job.*

**Also important**: *On my laptop (Ubuntu GNOME 17.04) the same joypad and the same version of ePSXe recognize it perfectly with no problems at all.*

I don't really know what to do D:

Here's what ePSXe shows us:
[image: ePSXe]

Comment: Why is the number for up so different from the other D-pad numbers? I would assume it should be similar. You said you did the same thing on your computer, what numbers did it give? Try manually entering those exact numbers, perhaps?

Comment: Agree with above, enter 386 in the box.

Comment: On my laptop it just shows a similar number. I don't remember it exactly, maybe 386.
By the way I can't enter it because it takes the number on the keyboard as a button of the controller :/

Comment: Do you have another controller that you can test on this computer? If the controller is confirmed working on another computer then it isn't the issue. What exactly is the controller? I'm thinking this may be a driver issue. As a "hackaround", you could remap through something like Joy2Key. Essentially, you map the controller button to a keyboard button you don't use (like numpad 7 or something), then map that in ePSXe to up on your virtual controller. However, if the problem is driver related, this will not work.

Comment: @NathanSmith I also tested DualShock 2 with an adapter and the problem is the same. (also it works like a charm on my laptop as the other generic joypad)